# Why is Label Text not Updating to Specified Variable(swift)

Tags: swift, macos

mega-noob question:

So right now I'm just trying to test my variable system in my gpa project. When popup button is altered it alters the value of a courses point total for example

```
override var representedObject: Any? {
    didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        func UPDTmathG(_ sender: Any) {

        if let title = (sender as AnyObject).titleOfSelectedItem, title == "A+" {
            mathPoints = 4.3;
        }
        if let title = (sender as AnyObject).titleOfSelectedItem, title == "A" {
            mathPoints = 4;
        }
```

Now to test that these variables are actually changing an learn how to change string values.

```
testLabel.stringValue = String(mathPoints);
```

Ideally, when this added to the `func UPDTmathG(_ sender: Any) {`.
It would update the string value of the label to be the value of the variable, but the string isn't updating. Any ideas?

Thanks:)

Comment: why don't you use ```testLabel.text = String(mathPoints);``` ?

Comment: it is cocoa osx, .stringValue is the osx equivalent of .text for ios

Comment: We're not getting the whole picture here.  Can you post a complete example that we can run, which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Are you calling that mathG function? From the code given it looks like its just being defined.